# Why do i get invalid use of void expression?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to recreate vectors in c, and i get an invalid use of void expression error. I have tried it like this.

```
typedef struct {
    void *data;
    int size;
    int capacity;
} vec;


#define vec_new(name, type) vec name; (name).size = 0; (name).capacity = 8; {\
    void *vec_temp; vec_temp = calloc(8, sizeof(type));\
    while (vec_temp == NULL) { vec_temp = calloc(8, sizeof(type)); }\
    (name).data = vec_temp;\
}


#define vec_set(vec, index, value, type) *( (type*) (vec).data[(index)] ) = value;
#define vec_get(vec, index, type) *( (type*) (vec).data[(index)] )`
```

I get the error in the set and get macros

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], preferably one that we can just copy-paste and try ourselves. Also add comments on the lines where you get the errors. And of course copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question.

Comment: I think you need parentheses to bind the cast more tightly; `(type *)((vec).data)` applies the type to the `void *` data member.

Comment: Just curious why you're retrying `calloc` in an infinite loop?  If it failed once it's probably going to keep on failing.  And if that's really what you want, then `do { } while` is less duplicative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing a `void*` type with the way things are.  You are typecasting `(vec).data[(index)]` to `type*`, you should be casting `((vec).data)` to `type*`

Try this instead:

```
#define vec_set(vec, index, value, type) ((type*) (vec).data)[(index)] = value;
#define vec_get(vec, index, type) (((type*) (vec).data)[(index)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting invalid use of void expression cos we cant do void* arithmatics and dereference ! you need to cast the `data` struct member and you did it wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    void *data;
    int size;
    int capacity;
} vec;


#define vec_new(name, type) vec name; (name).size = 0; (name).capacity = 8; {\
    void *vec_temp; vec_temp = calloc(8, sizeof(type));\
    while (vec_temp == NULL) { vec_temp = calloc(8, sizeof(type)); }\
    (name).data = vec_temp;\
}



#define vec_set(vec, index, value, type) (*( ( (type*) (vec).data )  + (index) ) ) = value;
#define vec_get(vec, index, type) (*( ( (type*) (vec).data )  + (index) ) )
int main()
{
    
    vec_new(p, int);
    vec_set(p,0,5,int);
    int g = vec_get(p, 0, int);
    
    printf("%d",g);
    return 0;
}
```